# EditorConfig in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, styles, editorconfig

There is an option in Android studio to enable EditorConfig support( defaultsettings->codingstyle dialog),but not sure how it works.Could you please let me know how to integrate .editorconfig file in the Andriod Studio project?

Answer (score 37):

The website [EditorConfig.org](http://editorconfig.org/) has a good explanation of how to get it set up. Android Studio has it built-in so there should be no need to add a plugin or set up Android Studio, just..

1. Add your `.editorconfig` file in the root directory of the project (as mentioned at [EditorConfig.org](http://editorconfig.org/))
2. Enable EditorConfig support (`Settings` → `Editor` → `Code Style` → `Enable EditorConfig support`)

**Note**:

> A search for .editorconfig files will stop if the root filepath is reached or an EditorConfig file with root=true is found.

#### Edit:

I would recommend starting with something along these lines, and tweaking it as your team sees fit:

```
# indicate this is the root of the project
root = true

[*.{kt,java,xml,gradle,md}]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
end_of_line = lf
```

Comment: I updated it to give a suggested `.editorconfig` file starting point.